# Can I use parenthesis to encapsulate information I want to convert into a string? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, parentheses

I want to divide two integers and then convert their result into a string. I have done this by putting the division into parentheses in an attempt to convert the result of the division into a string, instead of just the denominator. There don't seem to be any errors this way but I wanted to double check that this is proper syntax.

Note:@numer and @denom are both integers.

```
def redfrac
  gcd = @numer.gcd(@denom)

  if @denom != 0
    rednumer = (@numer/gcd).to_s
    reddenom = (@denom/gcd).to_s

    if reddenom == "1"
      puts rednumer
    else
      puts rednumer + "/" + reddenom
    end
  else
    puts "Cannot divide by 0"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 > (1.0 / 4.0).to_s
=> "0.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is quite legal.

But for this exact task you may use string interpolation:

```
def redfrac
  gcd = @numer.gcd(@denom)

  if @denom != 0
    rednumer = @numer/gcd
    reddenom = @denom/gcd

    if reddenom == 1
      puts "#{rednumer}"
    else
      puts "#{rednumer}/#{reddenom}"
    end
  else
    puts "Cannot divide by 0"
  end
end
```